# Pandas: check if data in a dataframe is equal to another data in another dataframe based on an ID column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to create a method where giving two dataframes as params:

df1:

```
colId | Price        | Product
-------------------------------
111   | 103.510      | LSFT11
112   | 100.220      | LSFT00
113   | 90.130       | LSFT11
114   | 75.500       | LSFT12
```

df2:

```
Id    | col_price    | col_product
-----------------------------------
001   | 100.500000   | LSFT01
111   | 103.510000   | LSFT11
112   | 100.220      | LSFT00
002   | 10.100000    | LSFT01
114   | 75.500000    | LSFT12
113   | 90.130000    | LSFT11
```

I want to check, row by row from `df1` if the data is equal to it's correspondent in `df2`, based on columns `colId` from `df1` and `Id` from `df2`, where:

-`Price` in `df1` should be equal to `col_price` in `df2`. Where the datatype is float for both columns but should take into consideration the number of franctions (i.e 103.510 = 103.510000)

-`Product` in `df1` should be equal to `col_product` in `df2`.

If OK, return `True`.
If NOT OK, return `df1` with additional column `Rejection` specifying what is NOK and `False`.

Example:
**with this df1 and always cheking with the same df2 above**:

```
colId | Price        | Product
-------------------------------
111   | 100.510      | LSFT11   ---> 100.510 <> 103.510000
112   | 100.220      | LSFT00
113   | 90.130       | LSFT12   ---> LSFT12 <> LSFT11
114   | 75.500       | LSFT12
```

If NOK, should return this `df` and `False`:

```
colId | Price        | Product | Rejection
-------------------------------------------
111   | 100.510      | LSFT11  | Price NOK
112   | 100.220      | LSFT00  |
113   | 90.130       | LSFT12  | Product NOK  
114   | 75.500       | LSFT12  |
```

What can be a + here, is to check that columns `Price` and `Product` both exist in the input `df1` before processing.
If OK, continue and check data (process explained above); if NOK, return directly `df1` with `Rejection` column to say columns do not exist + `False`

```
colId | Rejection
---------------------------------
111   | Column Price, Product NOK
112   | Column Price, Product NOK
113   | Column Price, Product NOK  
114   | Column Price, Product NOK
```

If only one column is missing in df1, example:

```
colId | Product | Rejection
----------------------------------
111   | LSFT11  | Column Price NOK
112   | LSFT00  | Column Price NOK
113   | LSFT12  | Column Price NOK 
114   | LSFT12  | Column Price NOK
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve this especially when dealing with huge data please?

Comment: To clarify your requirements.  You would like to create a function which takes in two dataframes, makes a set of comparisons based on the following logic:

Comment: @itprorh66 Yes, exact; and return a boolean True if OK; and a dataframe (df1 adding column rejection) and a boolean False if NOK. I have added this in the requirement. Thank you.

Comment: Is the output a new dataframe or modification of an existing dataframe?

Comment: The output is a modification of an existing dataframe (df1 inserted as an input in the examples above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas function [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) to get on dataframe with all the data and check if values are identical. Here is a minimal example that you can copy:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    [[111, "A"], [122, "B"], [133, "C"]], columns=["price", "product"]
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    [[112, "A"], [122, "C"], [133, "C"]], columns=["price", "product"]
)

df_merged = pd.merge(right=df1, left=df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=["_df1", "_df2"])
df_merged["product okay"] = df_merged["product_df1"] == df_merged["product_df2"]
df_merged["price okay"] = df_merged["price_df1"] == df_merged["price_df2"]
df_merged["both okay"] = df_merged["price okay"] & df_merged["product okay"]

df_merged
```

output is

[image]

the not-okay list is then simply the rows of the dataframe that are not both okay. These can be retrieved using the negation operator `~`:

```
df_merged[~df_merged["both okay"]]
```

Output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. But, this is checking giving the two dataframes order, the goal is to check based on columns `colId` from `df1` and `Id` from `df2`. Do you know how to do this with merge?

Comment: `df_merged = pd.merge(right=df1, left=df2, left_on="colId", right_on="Id", suffixes=["_df1", "_df2"])` you can merge on any column by passing `left_on` and `right_on` parameters to the function. If this works for you, please upvote and accept (the checkmark icon) my answer so I get rewared for my efforts :-)

Comment: It's done, thank you :)